# Surface Optimisation with Excel

Tags: excel, optimization, mathematical-optimization, surface

I've to make an optimisation for the manufacturing of wood plank.

I have **base planks** with two possible dimensions: `L1 x l1` and `L2 x l2`.

I was asked to **produce planks of different known dimensions** (in 1 or more copies for some) from these basic planks, the goal being to optimize the process and to **use as few base planks as possible**. Note that each plank must be made entirely from a same base board and thus cannot be made in 2 or more parts.

I first made a simple excel calculation on a single variable dimension but it did not take into account that a plank could be made under another one on a same base plank.

I then got interested in optimization. If I'm not mistaken I'm looking to optimize the difference between :

`the number of base boards x total area of a base board - sum of planks to make`

However, I have great difficulties to write mathematically the condition "*each board is entirely made from one and the same base board `L1 x l1` or `L2 x l2`*".

Does someone would know how to do that? I've looked on internet but I found nothing.Also do you think it's possible to do that on  basic Excel (I've never used VBA)?

Feel free to ask any questions  (my english isn't the best, sorry if my explaination isn't clear enough :) )

Thanks and have a good day :)

Comment: This is called the knapsack problem, there are plenty of code examples out there.  You should be able to find one that is close to what you need and can modify.  This is not possible with formula.

Comment: This is *not* a knapsack problem.  This is a cutting stock problem, and a 2-dimensional one, which makes it more complicated.  Do some research on "cutting stock" problems.  This *might* be doable in Excel, but you will more likely need to switch to a mathematical modeling language.  I would NOT try to tackle this with VBA.

Comment: "Linear Programming" can be used to solve both problems mentioned, but being "hard" problems, basic excel is quite unsuitable. Years ago I tried hooking LP_Solve into excel to do this but wasn't successful. However, I just noticed the OpenSolver plugin for excel at opensolver.org, and it seems to already do what I was attempting to "hook up" back then. Maybe have a look at it.

Comment: @Stax, linear programming is strictly speaking for continuous problems only. Mixed-integer programming is a better description.

Comment: Warning: this is not as simple a problem as you may think.